# Using AVR Dragon with Atmel Studio 6

Tags: avr, atmel, xmega, atmel-studio

I have an Xmega Xplained 128A1 kit along with an AVR Dragon.

Can anyone help me with the steps to be followed for programming Xmega using Dragon using Atmel Studio 6?

I have downloaded the material from the Atmel website and have the necessary codes and other stuff. Unfortunately, the manual shows the steps with Studio 5.

The steps which I took:

1. Created the project in Atmel Studio.
2. Added the include files to the project folder.
3. Built the project. Build was successful.
4. Then compiled it. Compilation was also successful.

Now what to do next. I tried debugging, but it was taking too long and thus cancelled it.

Comment: I used Atmel studio 6 last year so don't exactly remember where things are but did you select the micro from the list of micros in project settings?

Comment: Where can I find it? Currently, Project Menu has Show all files, Set as Start up project, Project Properties.

Comment: @DavidNorman: Do you remember from where you came to know about the steps to be followed? That can also help, if you remember site name or something similar.

Comment: I don't I figured out everything myself with no help of the internet. Under Project properties you should have selected the microcontroller. Can you read the signature from the micro?

Comment: Please wait for just a few minutes. Checking.

Comment: I tried device programming. It says "New Firmware availble for AVR Dragon. Upgrade to Continue"

Comment: yeah go for it update it

Comment: dont worry about that, did you upgrade it yet? upgrading will download the newer version of the AVR firmware

Comment: I read the device signature. What to do next?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9294/discussion-between-david-norman-and-sourabh)

Comment: @Sourabh I'm saying this from memory, because I have recently used AVR studio6. There should be a lightning bolt for "device programming" or something. If you click on that, there should be a "memories" tab, go there and pick your compiled file and assuming you have selected the correct HW during set-up, the rest should be explanatory.

Comment: @NickWilliams: Thanks a lot. Actually David helped me solving  it.

Comment: Someone should post what worked as an answer so we can 1) upvote it and 2) the question won't appear unanswered.

Comment: @Sourabh I don't see why not; anything that might help future visitors with the same or similar problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently installed Atmel Studio 6 and upgraded a project that had to be manualy recreated so I thought I'd document the process including use of an AVR Dragon. The first step was to create a new project and as my code was C++ I selected `GCC C++ Executable Project`:

[image: Project creation]

The next step is device selection, a search facility is provided that saves sifting through the entire list of devices:

[image: Device selection]

The next step required for most projects is to define the CPU frequency. I went into `Project | Properties` and went to the symbols tab for the compiler I'm using, in this case C++. There I defined F_CPU by pressing the add button and typing `F_CPU=11059200` to suit the crysyal I'm using. Once done the screen looks as follows (note that I corrected the value after taking the screenshot, it was missing a zero):

[image: Setting the F_CPU clock speed]

In the same area you can go down to the tool tab and define the type of debugger / programmer and the interface. In my case I was using the JTAG interface, different options will appear if using ISP but the defaults are normally OK.

[image: Selecting the debugger / programmer]

Once that's been saved you can click on the device programming icon on the toolbar or press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to get to the device programming screen.

[image: Device programming toolbar]

Once you've confirmed the correct tool, device and interface is selected you can press the apply button to connect. It's likely the AVR Dragon will require a firmware update to work so press the upgrade button if prompted to do so and wait for the upgrade to complete.

[image: Device programming screen]

Once connected you'll be able to read the device signature and target voltage to confirm the connection to the target is OK. You can also program the various memories, lockbits and lock bits from the same screen.

[image: Device programming]

However once your configuration bits are have been set you may find it more convenient to use the start without debugging button on the toolbar to launch the project. That will automatically build the project if required, program the device and start the program.

[image: Start without debugging]

Comment: The pictures made the entire procedure extremely clear. Thanks.